# Excel search - multiple words found to be printed with comma separated

Tags: excel

Excel problem:

I am currently have a pre-determined list of keywords to find in sentences in excel. For example, the list contains AA, BB, CC, DD and the column of sentences will/will not contain these key words. Currently, I am using this formula,

=INDEX(list,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,A3))*ROW($1:$3))).

list in this case is a range list that contains all the keywords, A3 is the cell I am interested in checking.

However, this method only words when the sentence has 1 keyword. For e.g: This sentence contains AA. - this will return the keyword AA. Should the sentence contain more than 1 keyword, I get a REF error. For e.g This sentence contains AA and BB - return REF error.

I am asking for your help for a solution where all the keywords can be printed, and should there be multiple keywords, they can be printed with comma separation. Is there any way to do that?

Really appreciate any help for this problem I am facing!

Best regards,
Luc

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 with the new Filter() function, this is a piece of cake. Start in A2 with this and copy down.

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(List,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(List,A2)))),"no match")
```

[image]

Comment: If that takes care of your problem, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. That's how you can say Thank you here.